# Certain property of the quotient ring related to polynomial rings and fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Yesteday I posted a question which got flagged as a duplicate. The reason I posted it was that I couldn't figure out a step in the solution provided to the duplicate so instead of reposting the already flagged question I will post the part that confused me.

The problem is the following

> Are there fields $F$ such that the rings $F[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$ and $F[x]/\langle x^2-1 \rangle$ are isomorphic?

The approach I took was to first suppose that there exists an isomorphism and then see what conditions it would need to satisfy. So suppose that $\varphi : F[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle \to F[x]/\langle x^2-1 \rangle$ is the isomorphism.

Then $\varphi(x) = a+bx + \langle x^2-1\rangle$ for $a,b \in F$. Now the dupe's solution claimed that this would imply that  $$(a+bx)^2 = k(x^2-1)$$ i.e that $a+bx$  is a multiple of $x^2-1$. I don't see where they got this conclusion. To me the only thing I can get out of $\varphi(x) = a+bx + \langle x^2-1\rangle$ is that I can write it as $$\varphi(x) = a+bx + \langle x^2-1\rangle = a+bx + p(x)(x^2-1), \ p(x) \in F[x].$$

So the question here is probably more about the properties of the quotient ring as I don't seem to understand where $(a+bx)^2 = k(x^2-1)$ is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By homomorphism properties, $\varphi(x^2) = \varphi(x)^2 = (a+bx)^2$ -- however $x^2 = 0$ in the domain, and homomorphisms preserve $0$. So $(a+bx)^2=0$ in the image, which is the polynomial identity you desire.

Comment: By this I would have that $$0 = \varphi(x^2) = (a+bx)^2 + \langle x^2 -1 \rangle = (a+bx)^2 + p(x)(x^2-1)$$ i.e $$-(a+bx)^2 = p(x)(x^2-1)$$ so I'll end up with the negative sing?

Comment: @Jaipur $p$ is an arbitrary polynomial, so the negative sign doesn't make a difference.